# How to store previous value of string from json and change value of const with react hooks?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm trying to create an event in gtm. I have a modal for payment that isn't handled by me but a third-party company, and when a user pays with card - in this example case we'll say 50 euro - I get this information from the backend:

```
event
params
{type: "setPaymentAmount", value: 50}
```

So in my code I use this to get the amount and use it in a google tagmanager-event using useEffectOnce from react-use:

```
useEffectOnce(() => {
  if (event.params.type === 'setPaymentAmount') {
    TagManager.dataLayer({
      dataLayer: {
        event: 'set_payment_amount',
        amount: `${event.params.value}`
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This works fine. Problem is that i sometimes receive the "setPaymentAmount"-value twice, (e.g. if the user runs into an error or has to enter the cvc-code of the card), which makes the gtm-event run twice. This can't be changed form the back-end so I would like to store the value of the amount and - were it to change - I would like to compare the old value and the new value and send a new gtm-event so that it's not confusing for the people at my job using gtm for analytics.

I have tried different solutions with useState, useEffect, useEffectOnce, useRef and usePrevious (both usePrevious with react-use and with useRef) but I think I might be misunderstanding how it works. When I use:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const prevCount = usePrevious(count);
```

and then try to set:

```
setCount(count = `${event.params.value}`);
```

I only get "count is constant" and with prevCount I only get "undefined".

In other experiments I'm able to change the value of a const in a return statement with an onClick for example. If someone could help me out here that would be much appreciated. If anything is unclear let me know and I'll try to explain it better.

Pleas and thank you!

Comment: You can't assign value to count variable because it is const. And `=` will return undefined.
So please change it to like this.
 
setCount(event.params.value);

Comment: So you have get from backend {type: "setPaymentAmount", value: 50}  and {type: "setPaymentAmount", value: 20} for example,  and your question is to compare value: 50 from one response and value: 20 from second response?

Comment: Ok! Can I then use that value inside another function? Because my gtm-event is in another function where I can not use hooks.

Comment: @AnnaVlasenko Yes, that is correct.

Comment: in this case you might have to store your value in `localStorage`
`localStorage.setItem('value', value);` and then get it in other file, where you don't have hooks

Comment: I'm still a bit confused about all of this. It works if I, for instance, set "setCount(count => count + 1)" but not if I do "setCount(count => count = event.params.value)" or some variable. How is it possible to add to it but not set it equal to the number of a variable?

Comment: @Joel8bitar why are you using arrow function inside setCount function?
Is this not working? setCount(event.params.value)

Comment: @NemanjaK No. I want to use it in an other function, but I still get the value 0 (from useState) if I try to do that.

Comment: @NemanjaK From the initial state I mean.